# Meaning of $L_t^\infty L^2(dx d\gamma)$ and $L_t^2 L^2(dx d\gamma)$

Tags: real-analysis, lp-spaces

I am referring to [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1812.05967.pdf), p. 7.

It is said im Lemma 1 that
$$
\frac{1}{2}\frac{d}{dt}\Vert f^\varepsilon(t)\rVert^2_{L^2(dx d\gamma)}+\frac{1}{\varepsilon^2}\Vert f^\varepsilon(t)-p^\varepsilon (t)M\Vert^2_{L^2(dxd\gamma)}\leqslant 0\tag{2.2}
$$
for each $t\geq 0$, in particular means that
$$
\max\left(\Vert f^\varepsilon\Vert^2_{L_t^\infty L^2(dxd\gamma)},\frac{2}{\varepsilon^2}\Vert f^\varepsilon-p^\varepsilon M\Vert^2_{L_t^2L^2(dxd\gamma)}\right)\leqslant\Vert f_0\Vert^2_{L^2(dxd\gamma)}\tag{2.3}.
$$

I do not completely understand how (2.2) implies (2.3).

---

First of all, we can of course multiply (2.2) by $2$ to get
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\Vert f^\varepsilon(t)\rVert^2_{L^2(dx d\gamma)}+\frac{2}{\varepsilon^2}\Vert f^\varepsilon(t)-p^\varepsilon (t)M\Vert^2_{L^2(dxd\gamma)}\leqslant 0
$$

Now, I guess they integrate with respect to time. But I do not know what the notations
$$
L_t^\infty L^2(dxd\gamma),\qquad L_t^2L^2(dxd\gamma)
$$
are supposed to mean and why in the first expression we have $L_t^\infty$ while in the second one we have $L_t^2$.

Comment: Not sure about the estimates and didn’t look too closely, but the notation $L^p_tL^q(dx\,d\gamma)$ means the space $L^p(\Bbb{R}; L^q(\Bbb{R}^2,dx\,d\gamma))$. An element of this space is an $L^p$ function, with respect to 1D Lebesgue measure, $f$ from the real line $\Bbb{R}$, and taking values in the Banach space $L^q(\Bbb{R}^2,dx\,d\gamma)$.

Comment: More generally, if you have measure spaces $(X,\mathfrak{M},\mu)$ and a Banach space $B$, then $L^p(\mu;B)$ denotes the $L^p$ functions $f:X\to B$ with respect to the measure $\mu$. If $B$ itself is another space $L^q(\nu)$ where $(Y,\mathfrak{N},\nu)$ is a measure space, it’s common to write $L^p_{\mu}L^q_{\nu}$ or $L^p_xL^q_y$ to denote the space $L^p(\mu; L^q(\nu))$.

Comment: Ah, ok! Then it remains to understand why in the first case one wants $p=\infty$ while in the second one, one wants $p=2$.

Comment: wait… don’t you just integrate (2.2) in time and use the FTC? it just looks complicated, but it’s nothing but the FTC

Comment: Could you give an explanation? I am not sure that I understand what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notation was already in the comments. For convenience, let $B=L^2(dx\,d\gamma)$. The inequality follows immediately once you integrate in time. You get for all $t\geq 0$,
\begin{align}
\|f^{\epsilon}(t)\|_B^2-\|f^{\epsilon}(0)\|_B^2+\frac{2}{\epsilon^2}\int_0^t\|f^{\epsilon}(s)-p^{\epsilon}(s)M\|_B^2\,ds&\leq 0,
\end{align}
or rearranging,
\begin{align}
\|f^{\epsilon}(t)\|_B^2+\frac{2}{\epsilon^2}\int_0^t\|f^{\epsilon}(s)-p^{\epsilon}(s)M\|_B^2\,ds&\leq \|f_0\|_B^2.
\end{align}
Since this is true for all $t\geq 0$, we find that
\begin{align}
\sup_{t\geq 0}\|f^{\epsilon}(t)\|_B^2+\frac{2}{\epsilon^2}\int_0^{\infty}\|f^{\epsilon}(s)-p^{\epsilon}(s)M\|_B^2\,ds&\leq \|f_0\|_B^2.
\end{align}
Hence,
\begin{align}
\|f^{\epsilon}\|_{L^{\infty}([0,\infty);B)}^2+\frac{2}{\epsilon^2}\|f^{\epsilon}-p^{\epsilon}M\|_{L^2([0,\infty);B)}^2&\leq \|f_0\|_B^2.
\end{align}
For the first term, I used the fact that sup of square of non-negative numbers is square of sup, and for the second term, it’s just definition.

Comment: If I got you correctly, you take the supremum
$$
\sup_{t\geq 0}\left(\Vert f^{\epsilon}(t)\Vert_B^2+\frac{2}{\epsilon^2}\int_0^t\Vert f^\epsilon(s)-p^\epsilon(s)M\Vert_B^2\, ds\right)
$$

For the second summand, the supremum is taken for $t=\infty$. But for the first summand, I did not understand yet how you reach $L^\infty$.

Comment: Tell me how is the infinity norm defined

Comment: It is defined as $\Vert f\Vert_{L^\infty}=\inf \sup \vert f(x)\vert$, where the infimum is taken over all null sets and the supremum is taken over all elements not in the null set.

Comment: Ok so do you agree that is bounded above by the supremum?

Comment: I agree that $\Vert f^\varepsilon (t)\Vert_B^2\leq\sup_{t\geq 0}\Vert f^\varepsilon (t)\Vert_B^2$.

Comment: So the infinity norm of the LHS is bounded by the RHS. This is just basic definitions of L infinity, nothing specific to your PDE stuff here, so I suggest you review that